# What is the mapping from purely imaginary quaternions to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: vectors, quaternions

It is claimed that $q = x{\bf i} + y{\bf j} + z{\bf k}$ has an one to one mapping to a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ where $v = x \hat i + y \hat j + z \hat k$

But ${\bf i}, {\bf j},{\bf k}$ are complex unit quaternion and $\hat i$ is a unit vector, so although they have similar notation, they are not the same quantity

What would be a mapping that takes a quaternion $q$ to a vector $v$?

Comment: The coefficients of $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ in $q$ are unique, so you can extract $x,y,z$ from $q$, and thus it makes sense (i.e. well-defined) to map $q$ to $v$.  I can give a mapping $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ via $x\mapsto (x,0)$.  Sure, $x$ and $(x,0)$ aren't the same object, but why would we be interested in this map if they were?

Comment: @Hayden Would it be possible to define this mapping in term of a function? Because a mapping has always been a mathematical operation for me and I am not comfortable with the idea of mapping being some sort of embedding or extraction

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  The assignment $x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}\mapsto (x,y,z)$ defines a function.  If you mean that you're not comfortable with a function not being of some composition of simple functions like addition/subtraction/multiplication/complex conjugation/etc, then you are severely limiting what a function can be and the more general definition of a function is probably something you'll find useful to get used to.

Comment: I meant we can perhaps define a function $f({\bf i}, {\bf j}, {\bf k}, \hat i, \hat j, \hat k )$ that takes in quaternion $q$ and spits out a vector $v$ such that $\hat i$ is attached to $x$ and ${\bf i}$ is cancelled or reduced to multiplication by $1$. Something like that

Comment: There is no need to do such a thing. @Hayden has defined the function completely. To make an analogy, a function can be a black box: as long as you have a complete description of the output and input, there is no need to know what's going on "inside".

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Expanding upon what Muphrid said: A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a triple $f=(A,B,F)$ where $F\subset A\times B$ satisfies the properties that $(a,b),(a,b')\in F$ implies $b=b'$ and for every $a\in A$ there is a $b\in B$  (denoted $f(a)$, usually) such that $(a,b)\in F$.  Nothing in there says how $a$ goes to $b$, just that it does, and that's all you need. Your notation doesn't make much sense to me; I think what you want is a function taking a purely imaginary quaternion as an argument and spitting out a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quaternions and  $\mathbb{R}^4$ are isomorphes as vectorial spaces; you can apply the subspace of base {**i**, **j**, **k**} of $\mathbb{H}$ bijectively onto any subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated for any base {$b_1$,$b_2$,$b_3$} and in particular the base standard of your question.